# macOS Excel missing fonts warning

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I keep getting this warning in macOS Excel: "We were unable to load all your fonts. Some fonts may be missing". I tried solutions in [Microsoft support doc](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/issues-with-fonts-in-office-for-macos-66a299b2-47ec-43bd-a196-a56b94d2ae88) but nothing work.

Comment: WIth the information provided, all we can say is "try again?". Please take the time to [read this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I have tried several times.

Comment: I am getting this too, after moving my stuff (including fonts) to a new system. I wonder if one of the font files got corrupted in the process, or is no longer compatible, but I have yet to find which one it could be. Unfortunately Excel doesn't give any hint as to which fonts couldn't be loaded.